# C++ Problem with a class template

Tags: c++, templates

Why won't this template compile?

```
template <class K, class V = Referenced>
class Cache
{
public:
    Cache();
    ...
};

template <class K, class V>
Cache::Cache()   <====  location of compiler error (see below)
{
    ...
}
```

**ERROR** `error: 'template<class K, class V> class Cache' used without template parameters`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify the template parameters:

```
template <class K, class V>
Cache<K, V>::Cache()
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
template <class K, class V>
Cache<K,V>::Cache() // Specify the template parameters
{
   //...

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
template <class K, class V>
Cache<K, V>::Cache()
{
    ...
}
```

Notice the template parameters following the class name.